# modifying the JSON key / value pair within object

Tags: python, json, formatting

I have a JSON file which was taken from an API call that was made.

The issue is that the "**name**" value actually correlates to the other value "**smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890**"

The keys named "attribute_value" and "attribute_name" are worthless to me.

I would like to make "name" the key and "smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890" the value. 
Is there a way to do this in Python?

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_value": "smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890",
        "attribute_name": "name"
    },
    {
        "attribute_value": "MS18-4057142",
        "attribute_name": "msft"
    }
],
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions and help.

Comment: Yes, there is a way do that in Python (by writing code). The first step would be to *deserialize* the JSON, which ends up with a Python object-graph (of dict/list/string, see the appropriate documentation). Then, perform a "useful" transformation on this object-graph and re-serialize the result back to JSON.

Comment: I think the part where you said  " "useful" transformation  " could use some more detail. Perhaps an example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about this as JSON. Once you've parsed it, it's just a dictionary, whose only value is a list of dictionaries. You want to transform those dictionaries.

---

First, how do you transform this dictionary:

```
d = {'attribute_value': 'smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890', 'attribute_name': 'name'}
```

… into this one:

```
{'name': 'smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890'}
```

That's pretty easy:

```
d = {d['attribute_name']: d['attribute_value']}
```

Let's wrap that up in a function:

```
def transform_attribute(d):
    return {d['attribute_name']: d['attribute_value']}
```

---

OK, now if you have a list of such dictionaries, like this:

```
ds = [
    {'attribute_value': 'smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890', 'attribute_name': 'name'},
    {'attribute_value': 'MS18-4057142', 'attribute_name': 'msft'}
]
```

… how do you transform all of them? Just write a list comprehension:

```
ds = [transform_attribute(d) for d in ds]
```

Again, let's make a function:

```
def transform_attributes(ds):
    return [transform_attribute(d) for d in ds]
```

---

OK, so if you have a dict whose values are lists like that, how do you transform this:

```
dds = {
    "attributes": [
        {'attribute_value': 'smb_nt_ms18_jan_4056890', 'attribute_name': 'name'},
        {'attribute_value': 'MS18-4057142', 'attribute_name': 'msft'}
    ]}
```

That's just a dictionary comprehension:

```
dds = {key: transform_attributes(ds) for key, ds in dds.items()}
```

You can wrap that one up too:

```
def transform_attributes_dict(dds):
    return {key: transform_attributes(value) for key, value in dds.items()}
```

Or maybe it's not a dictionary comprehension; maybe you only want to change the value associated with `'attributes'`? Your example only has one key/value, so it's hard to know which one you want. But that's, if anything, even easier:

```
dds['attributes'] = transform_attributes(dds['attributes'])
```

---

If you want to try to make it all more concise after you've got it working, you can inline the functions into the middle of one big expression. But if you push that all the way, it's probably not too easy to read:

```
dds = {key: transform_attributes(value) for key, value in dds.items()}

dds = {key: [transform_attribute(d) for d in value] for key, value in dds.items()}

dds = {key: [{d['attribute_name']: d['attribute_value']} for d in value]
       for key, value in dds.items()}
```